# Joining data from two tables in Oracle Using INSTR

Tags: oracle, left-join

I have 2 tables `TAB_A` and `TAB_B`. I want to write a query where `TAB_A` is driving table(essentially `TAB_A` will be on LEFT SIDE in LEFT OUTER JOIN). I have to join using columns A1 and A2 from `TAB_A` and B1 from `TAB_B`. B1 will have concatenation of A1 and A2 along with other characters in the same column.

I tried something like below:

```
SELECT A.*, B.B3
FROM TAB_A A LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB_B B
ON INSTR(B.B1, A.A1||'-'||A.A2) > 0;
```

However, this query is going on forever. Please note that it's an Oracle DB.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
A1||'-'||A2 can be present anywhere in the B1.

```
e.g. A1 = X103
A2 = VN12345
B1 = 1w466X103-VN12345HG0034
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ON B.B1 LIKE '%'||A.A1||'-'||A.A2||'%';` ?

Comment: Addtionally to using `LIKE` you should add indices: on TAB_B add an index on column B1 and on TAB_A add an index on the construct `'%'||A.A1||'-'||A.A2||'%'`...

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I tried index as well as LIKE operator. This is very expensive in terms of performance. Both tables have millions of records.

Comment: Hi Sid,  is the join condition always in the  beginning in the A table or can it be in the middle - if it is in the beginning then the join can be written like: **ON B.B1 LIKE A.A1||'-'||A.A2||'%';**. Is that true and does that help with better performance?

Comment: HI A1||'-||A2 can be present anywhere in the column B1.

Comment: What is the maximum length of the columns `A1` resp. `A2`? In other words, can you live with a query that process the columns only up to a certain length?

Answer (score 0):

This is tha answer why the statement *is going on forever*.

If you investigate the execution plan you see something like this

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |   500 | 45000 |   113   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER|       |   500 | 45000 |   113   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB_A |   100 |  4400 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB_B |     5 |   230 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter(INSTR("B"."B1"(+),"A"."A1"||'-'||"A"."A2")>0)
```

So firat you `FULL SCAN` the table `TAB_A` and **for each row** of it you `FULL SCAN` the table `TAB_B`.

Technicall you calculate a *cartesian join* of the two tables (containing count(TAB_A) * count(TAB_B) rows) and then you filter the matches.

BTW no reformulation of the predicate (with LIKE etc.) will change this behavior - this chnage only the FILTER predicate.

The only thing that comes to my mind you can do - if you are lucky and the `TAB_B` contains a lot of rows without the *minus* sigh, to filter them out as those rows per definition can't match and create a smaller temporary table that is used in the join.

```
create table tab_b_tmp as
select * from tab_b
where b1 like '%-%' /* eliminate all rows that can't match */
;
```

You may possibly extend this logic if you find some additional elimination patterns based on your data.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding in `TAB_A` the column `A1` can be in left side of the string before `-` in the column `B1` from table `TAB_B` and column `A2` from table `TAB_A` can be in the remaining half of the string of column `B1` of table `TAB_B`.

Below query will give the result.

`select * from TAB_A A left outer join TAB_B B on substr(B.B1,1,instr(B.B1,'-')-1) like '%'||A.A1||'%' and substr(B.B1,instr(B.B1,'-')+1) like '%'||A.A2||'%';`

Comment: Unforunately this query use the same exceution plan as the original query, so for two tables with a *million of rows* it will produce a result set containing **1000 of billions** of rows, so the approach of reformulation the FILTER condition is probably not the solution.